# Perform an AJAX call using Django Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, django-forms

I am using the `<form>` tag to make a search bar and `submit` button. I would like my `submit` button to both query database and show a hidden `<div>`. The hidden `div` contains the database that will show the results.

I've successfully been able to query database, and display '`div` upon submit, but my problem is getting them to work together. Currently, I have to turn one off to make the other work. Together, the `submit` button causes page to refresh thus hiding div again. I have been told making an `AJAX` call will solve problem but need help in the code. More specifically the proper syntax for the `AJAX` call and if I'm missing anything in my `views.py`.

index.html:

```
<form method="GET" action="">
    <input type='text' name='q' value='{{ request.GET.q }}'></input>
    <input type='submit' onclick='showDiv()'></input>
</form>
```

(hidden) div:

```
<div id="hiddenDiv" style="display: none;">
<p>This is hidden search results<p>
</div>
```

views.py:

```
def index(request):
  var_1 = Products.objects.all()
  var_2 = request.GET.get("q")
  if var_2:
    var_1 = items.filter(
        Q(First__icontains=var_2) |
        Q(Last__icontains=var_2)
        )
  context = {'items': items,
  }
  return render(request, 'app/index.html', context)
```

broken javascript (not sure how to move querystring along):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); //stop submit     

        $.ajax({ //insert AJAX
            type: "GET",
            url "app/index.html",  
            data: {
                'var_2': 'var_2'.val() //take querystring
            },
            success:function showDiv(){ //activate javascript
                document.getElementById("welcomeDiv").style.display = "block";
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery AJAX submit form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960240/jquery-ajax-submit-form)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this.

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template.loader import render_to_string

def search_query(request):
    var_1 = Products.objects.all()
    var_2 = request.GET.get("q")
    if var_2:
        items = items.filter(
         Q(First__icontains=var_2) |
         Q(Last__icontains=var_2)
        )
    response = render_to_string('templates/template_name.html', {'items': items})
return HttpResponse(response)
```

**template_name.html**

```
<table width='100%'>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>xxxxx</th>
    <th>YYYYY</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  {% for item in items %}
  <tr>
    <td><b>{{ item.xxxx }}</b></td>
    <td><b>{{ item.yyyyyy }}</b></td>
    ......................
    .......................
  </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</tbody>
</table>
```

**javascript.js**

```
.........
.........
var search_query = $('#id_search_q').val();
$.ajax({ //insert AJAX
        type: "GET",
        url "api/search-query/",  
        data: {'q': search_query //take querystring
        },
        success:function(response){ //activate javascript
            $("#welcomeDiv").html(response)
        }

........
........
```

**index.html**

```
<form method="GET" action="">
    <input type='text' id='id_search_q' name='q' value='{{ request.GET.q }}'></input>
    <input type='submit' onclick='showDiv()'></input>
</form>
```

**urls.py**

```
url('^api/search-query/$', 'views.search_query', name='api_search_query')
```

Comment: I'm new to this, but are you certain I should be putting `var_2` under the `data` part of the ajax call? I am being told by chrome that `var_2` is not a function. I think this has been my problem all along, capturing the variable into the call

Comment: I haven't yet fully mastered javascript or even django for that matter, but if i have other js files linked to it, does the order I display them in the html file matter? I fear this is causing a problem. Changing the order of them gives me different errors.

Comment: I got it to work (slightly), but I made quite a few changes: the bottom line is: I don't have any errors, a `GET` request is being made, however it doesnt make the connection to the view. The problem definitely lies in the views.py. Where can I post my new code? Should I make a new question?

Comment: You should add new url '/api/search-query/' in urls.py file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111801/discussion-between-anoop-and-ceuskervin).

Comment: Thank you for getting me on the right path. I found this [link] (https://www.fir3net.com/Web-Development/Django/how-do-i-use-ajax-along-side-django.html) which further explained what you were trying to tell me. I adjusted the ajax view to return an html page with a table that iterated over each response. This is great! thanks.